# Issue with chakra UI CSS

Tags: css, next.js, frontend, chakra-ui

I am trying to display a card using **chakra UI** and **next js** but the CSS of chakra UI is messed up and all of my components are now not being shown incorrectly, It seemed to work well till yesterday. deleting the **.next** folder and rebuilding the application didn't help. Do you guys have any idea about fixing this

- My initial site used to look like this => https://www.thegogamicblog.xyz/
- Now my site looks like this => https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR25q.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changes the version of chakra UI from `1.8.x` to `2.0.0-next.1` and everything works :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).